# how to delete this git bash untracked list

Tags: git, github, git-bash

"I accidentally uploaded these files to git. Now upon giving "ls" command, i saw all these files in my untracked list. pls some one help me to delete all these things and clean my git queue list."

[image: this is a gitbash log image]

Comment: `ls` just gives a list of files in a folder - has nothing to do with git. You are listing the content of the users/your home folder.

Comment: Do I get you right, that you accidentally initialized a git repository in your windows user folder by running `git init`? And now whenever you execute `git status` everything that we see in your screenshot also lists as untracked files?

Comment: Apart from @fredrik 's remarks: what do you mean by "uploaded to git" and "git queue list"? Can you share what git commands did you run before the "problem" started happening? You can read more about ignoring files in Git [here](https://notes-on-git-and-github.netlify.app/html/10_ignoring_files.html)

Comment: I opened my file explorer and dived into my local disk c to search for a file.i accidentally clicked "git bash here" on local disk window. And from then on, all these files are appearing on my untracked list upon using "git status". I tries a command which is something like this."git clear -fdx" and all my files and app data on c drive was deleted. I didn't even had a backup. Pls help me fix this issue.there are like 5000 files on my git untracked list...

Comment: Yes i didn't create a repository yet. But these are all untracked files.pls help.

Comment: simply delete `.git` directory to remove git from your C directory

Comment: "git bash here" doesn't create anything; it just opens that window - "git bash" is just the name of the program (actually a bundled copy of [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) running on top of [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW)). As others have said, "ls" has nothing to do with git, these files aren't "untracked", they're just ... files. If you didn't mean to open the window, you can just close it. If the files are listed as "untracked" somewhere, then a) you've done something you haven't mentioned; and b) you haven't shown us that output.

Comment: all my files are deleted so i have no choice but had to fully reset my pc. i done that and freshly installed all the softwares and plugins and i also installed git now. I configured my name and email and checked once again the status off the git queue and again all these files are appearing in red color and saying that these files are from my untracked list.